# SSMS keyboard shortcut for save only the focused Query

Tags: ssms

I am running SQL Server Management Studio 19.1.56.0 with a project solution that has about 10 Queries.  When I save, either with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and default keyboard shortcuts, SSMS will rapidly change focus through all of my queries in the solution.

Not only is this highly distracting, but it does not end me in the same Query that I had focused when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for just saving the one query I have focused?

Comment: Strange. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-ver16) says: "Save the selected item  CTRL+S".

Comment: That threw me off, maybe the "selected item" in this case is the selected project/solution?

Comment: Everything is possible where bugs are concerned.

Comment: I'm seeing similar. Ctrl + S and Ctrl + Shift + S both only save the current tab. SSMS v18.8

Comment: @Eric: **I'm running the same version of the SSMS (19.1.56.0) and this works fine for me.** When one of queries is focused the _Ctrl+S_ saves only the current query, the _Ctrl+Shift+S__ saves all queries, without changing focus. BTW, when current selection is focused on the project in the _Solution Explorer_ tab then _Ctrl+S_ saves all the queries (without changing focus too).

Comment: @Eric: The **"selected item"** is what you currently selected on the _Solution Explorer_ tab.